# Parallax image won't center when I slide

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />

            <title>gallery</title>

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gallerystyle.css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.28468.js"></script>
            <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Economica:700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        </head>

        <body>
                <header>
                <div id="da-slider" class="da-slider">
                    <div class="da-slide">
                        <div class="da-img"><img src="gallery/comingsoon.jpg" alt="image01" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="da-slide">
                        <div class="da-img"><img src="gallery/map.png" alt="image01" /></div>
                    </div>

                    <nav class="da-arrows">
                        <span class="da-arrows-prev"></span>
                        <span class="da-arrows-next"></span>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
```

A Little bit of jscript here

```
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cslider.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {

                    $('#da-slider').cslider();

                });
            </script>   
        </body>
    </html>
```

THIS IS WHERE THE CSS BEGINS

```
     body   {
            padding-top:150px;
        }

        .da-slider{
            width: 100%;
            min-width: 520px;
            height: 450px;
            position: relative;
            margin: 30px auto;
            overflow: hidden;
            background: transparent url(gallery/stardust.png) repeat 0% 0%;
            border-top: 8px solid #efc34a;
            border-bottom: 8px solid #efc34a;
            box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0px -2px 1px #fff;
            -webkit-transition: background-position 1.4s ease-in-out 0.3s;
            -moz-transition: background-position 1.4s ease-in-out 0.3s;
            -o-transition: background-position 1.4s ease-in-out 0.3s;
            -ms-transition: background-position 1.4s ease-in-out 0.3s;
            transition: background-position 1.4s ease-in-out 0.3s;
        }
        .da-slide{
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .da-slide p {
            padding-top:10px;
        }

        .da-slide-current{
            z-index: 1000;
        }
        .da-slider-fb .da-slide{
            left: 100%;
        }
        .da-slider-fb  .da-slide.da-slide-current{
            left: 0px;
        }
        .da-slide h2,
        .da-slide p,
        .da-slide .da-link,
        .da-slide .da-img{
            position: absolute;
            opacity: 0;
            left: 110%;
        }
        .da-slider-fb .da-slide h2,
        .da-slider-fb .da-slide p,
        .da-slider-fb .da-slide .da-link{
            left: 10%;
            opacity: 1;
        }
        .da-slider-fb .da-slide .da-img{
            left: 60%;
            opacity: 1;
        }
        .da-slide h2{
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 66px;
            width: 50%;
            top: 60px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            z-index: 10;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
            font-family: 'Economica', Arial, sans-serif;
            font-weight: 700;
        }
        .da-slide p{
            width: 45%;
            top: 155px;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 26px;
            height: 80px;
            overflow: hidden;
            font-style: italic;
            font-family: 'Economica', Arial, sans-serif;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-style: italic;
        }
        .da-slide .da-img{
            text-align: center;
            width: 30%;
            top: 10px;
            height: 256px;
            line-height: 320px;
            left: 110%; /*60%*/
        }

        .da-dots{
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            text-align: center;
            left: 0px;
            bottom: 20px;
            z-index: 2000;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
        }
        .da-dots span{
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            width: 12px;
            height: 12px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: #e4b42d;
            margin: 3px;
            cursor: pointer;
            box-shadow: 
                1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset, 
                1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
        }
        .da-dots span.da-dots-current:after{
            content: '';
            width: 8px;
            height: 8px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 2px;
            left: 2px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: rgb(255,255,255);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%, rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(47%,rgba(246,246,246,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(237,237,237,1)));
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%,rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%,rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%,rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
            background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%,rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed',GradientType=0 );
        }
        .da-arrows{
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
        }
        .da-arrows span{
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            height: 30px;
            width: 30px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: #e4b42d;
            cursor: pointer;
            z-index: 2000;
            opacity: 0;
            box-shadow: 
                1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset, 
                1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
            -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out 0.2s;
            -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out 0.2s;
            -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out 0.2s;
            -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out 0.2s;
            transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out 0.2s;
        }
        .da-slider:hover .da-arrows span{
            opacity: 1;
        }
        .da-arrows span:after{
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            top: 5px;
            left: 5px;
            background: transparent url(gallery/arrows.png) no-repeat top left;
            border-radius: 50%;
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        }
        .da-arrows span:hover:after{
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        }
        .da-arrows span:active:after{
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
        }
        .da-arrows span.da-arrows-next:after{
            background-position: top right;
        }
        .da-arrows span.da-arrows-prev{
            left: 15px;
        }
        .da-arrows span.da-arrows-next{
            right: 15px;
        }
```

This is the small bit I edited so that the image is centered at the start instead of being off to the right side.

```
        .da-slide-current .da-img{
            left: 25%;
            opacity: 1;
        }
```

All animations from here on out pretty much

```
        /* Animation classes and animations */
```

Slide in from the right

```
        .da-slide-fromright .da-img{
            -webkit-animation: fromRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
            -moz-animation: fromRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
            -o-animation: fromRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
            -ms-animation: fromRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
            animation: fromRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes fromRightAnim1{
            0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes fromRightAnim2{
            0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes fromRightAnim3{
            0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
            1%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes fromRightAnim4{
            0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 60%; opacity: 1; }
        }

        @-moz-keyframes fromRightAnim1{
            0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @-moz-keyframes fromRightAnim2{
            0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @-moz-keyframes fromRightAnim3{
            0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
            1%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @-moz-keyframes fromRightAnim4{
            0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 60%; opacity: 1; }
        }

        @-o-keyframes fromRightAnim1{
            0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @-o-keyframes fromRightAnim2{
            0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @-o-keyframes fromRightAnim3{
            0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
            1%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @-o-keyframes fromRightAnim4{
            0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 60%; opacity: 1; }
        }

        @-ms-keyframes fromRightAnim1{
            0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @-ms-keyframes fromRightAnim2{
            0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @-ms-keyframes fromRightAnim3{
            0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
            1%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @-ms-keyframes fromRightAnim4{
            0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 60%; opacity: 1; }
        }

        @keyframes fromRightAnim1{
            0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @keyframes fromRightAnim2{
            0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @keyframes fromRightAnim3{
            0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
            1%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @keyframes fromRightAnim4{
            0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 60%; opacity: 1; }
        }
```

Slide in from the left

```
        .da-slide-fromleft .da-img{
            -webkit-animation: fromLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
            -moz-animation: fromLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
            -o-animation: fromLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
            -ms-animation: fromLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
            animation: fromLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes fromLeftAnim1{
            0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes fromLeftAnim2{
            0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes fromLeftAnim3{
            0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
            1%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes fromLeftAnim4{
            0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 60%; opacity: 1; }
        }

        @-moz-keyframes fromLeftAnim1{
            0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @-moz-keyframes fromLeftAnim2{
            0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @-moz-keyframes fromLeftAnim3{
            0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
            1%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @-moz-keyframes fromLeftAnim4{
            0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 60%; opacity: 1; }
        }

        @-o-keyframes fromLeftAnim1{
            0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @-o-keyframes fromLeftAnim2{
            0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @-o-keyframes fromLeftAnim3{
            0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
            1%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @-o-keyframes fromLeftAnim4{
            0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 60%; opacity: 1; }
        }

        @-ms-keyframes fromLeftAnim1{
            0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @-ms-keyframes fromLeftAnim2{
            0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @-ms-keyframes fromLeftAnim3{
            0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
            1%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @-ms-keyframes fromLeftAnim4{
            0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 60%; opacity: 1; }
        }

        @keyframes fromLeftAnim1{
            0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @keyframes fromLeftAnim2{
            0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @keyframes fromLeftAnim3{
            0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
            1%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 10%; opacity: 1; }
        }
        @keyframes fromLeftAnim4{
            0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 60%; opacity: 1; }
        }
```

Slide out to the right

```
        .da-slide-toright .da-img{
            -webkit-animation: toRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in both;
            -moz-animation: toRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in both;
            -o-animation: toRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in both;
            -ms-animation: toRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in both;
            animation: toRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in both;
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes toRightAnim1{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes toRightAnim2{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes toRightAnim3{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            99%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes toRightAnim4{
            0%{ left: 60%;  opacity: 1; }
            30%{ left: 55%;  opacity: 1; }
            100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
        }

        @-moz-keyframes toRightAnim1{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @-moz-keyframes toRightAnim2{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @-moz-keyframes toRightAnim3{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            99%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @-moz-keyframes toRightAnim4{
            0%{ left: 60%;  opacity: 1; }
            30%{ left: 55%;  opacity: 1; }
            100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
        }

        @-o-keyframes toRightAnim1{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @-o-keyframes toRightAnim2{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @-o-keyframes toRightAnim3{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            99%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @-o-keyframes toRightAnim4{
            0%{ left: 60%;  opacity: 1; }
            30%{ left: 55%;  opacity: 1; }
            100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
        }

        @-ms-keyframes toRightAnim1{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @-ms-keyframes toRightAnim2{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @-ms-keyframes toRightAnim3{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            99%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @-ms-keyframes toRightAnim4{
            0%{ left: 60%;  opacity: 1; }
            30%{ left: 55%;  opacity: 1; }
            100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
        }

        @keyframes toRightAnim1{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @keyframes toRightAnim2{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @keyframes toRightAnim3{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            99%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @keyframes toRightAnim4{
            0%{ left: 60%;  opacity: 1; }
            30%{ left: 55%;  opacity: 1; }
            100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
        }
```

Slide out to the left

```
        .da-slide-toleft .da-img{
            -webkit-animation: toLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
            -moz-animation: toLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
            -o-animation: toLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
            -ms-animation: toLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
            animation: toLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes toLeftAnim1{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            30%{ left: 15%;  opacity: 1; }
            100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes toLeftAnim2{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            30%{ left: 15%;  opacity: 1; }
            100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes toLeftAnim3{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            99%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes toLeftAnim4{
            0%{ left: 60%;  opacity: 1; }
            40%{ left: 70%;  opacity: 1; }
            90%{ left: 0%;  opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
        }

        @-moz-keyframes toLeftAnim1{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            30%{ left: 15%;  opacity: 1; }
            100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @-moz-keyframes toLeftAnim2{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            30%{ left: 15%;  opacity: 1; }
            100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @-moz-keyframes toLeftAnim3{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            99%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @-moz-keyframes toLeftAnim4{
            0%{ left: 60%;  opacity: 1; }
            40%{ left: 70%;  opacity: 1; }
            90%{ left: 0%;  opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
        }

        @-o-keyframes toLeftAnim1{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            30%{ left: 15%;  opacity: 1; }
            100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @-o-keyframes toLeftAnim2{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            30%{ left: 15%;  opacity: 1; }
            100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @-o-keyframes toLeftAnim3{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            99%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @-o-keyframes toLeftAnim4{
            0%{ left: 60%;  opacity: 1; }
            40%{ left: 70%;  opacity: 1; }
            90%{ left: 0%;  opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
        }

        @-ms-keyframes toLeftAnim1{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            30%{ left: 15%;  opacity: 1; }
            100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @-ms-keyframes toLeftAnim2{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            30%{ left: 15%;  opacity: 1; }
            100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @-ms-keyframes toLeftAnim3{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            99%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @-ms-keyframes toLeftAnim4{
            0%{ left: 60%;  opacity: 1; }
            40%{ left: 70%;  opacity: 1; }
            90%{ left: 0%;  opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
        }

        @keyframes toLeftAnim1{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            30%{ left: 15%;  opacity: 1; }
            100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @keyframes toLeftAnim2{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            30%{ left: 15%;  opacity: 1; }
            100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @keyframes toLeftAnim3{
            0%{ left: 10%;  opacity: 1; }
            99%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
        }
        @keyframes toLeftAnim4{
            0%{ left: 60%;  opacity: 1; }
            40%{ left: 70%;  opacity: 1; }
            90%{ left: 0%;  opacity: 0; }
            100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
        }
```

Comment: take the leading text out of the code format so it will wrap and people can read it:

Comment: Sorry I think I removed it!

Comment: Please help I'm making a parallax gallery type thing and well when it starts out the image is centered but when I press the button to the right the image blinks to the right then scrolls left and then from then on the images are always on the right side instead of being centered the way I want.

Comment: Thank you Carol I forgot to do that, new guy here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you have a `</div>` instead of a `</header>`
- would it be that you only have the centering happening on the current one, so the following ones may not be the current one as you may be thinking? because of where the focus is put after clicking:

  .da-slide .da-img{ left: 110%; }

  .da-slide-current .da-img{ left: 25%; }

Comment: Beaut! :) Glad I could help.